# Installation airflow through the docker compose

Tags: airflow

Please tell me, I install the airflow locally through the docker compose on window 10. The installation is already in its fourth hour. Is this how it should be?

Comment: no, it should be quite fast (download the airflow, postgres, redis take most of the time). check for any log. run docker ps -a and see the health status of the dockers

Answer (score 0):

Airflow installation through docker compose should not be taking 4 hours to complete. At most, the installation can take up to half an hour, perhaps you should try start over your installation process.